Strapi S3 Bucket integration
Issue with AWS S3 Integration in Strapi
I've integrated AWS S3 as per the documentation in @strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3, and it was working fine. However, since yesterday, it has stopped working.
config/plugin.js
module.exports = () => ({});


module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: 'aws-s3',
      providerOptions: {
        accessKeyId: env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        secretAccessKey: env('AWS_ACCESS_SECRET'),
        region: env('AWS_REGION'),
        params: {
          ACL: env('AWS_ACL', 'public-read'),
          signedUrlExpires: env('AWS_SIGNED_URL_EXPIRES', 15 * 60),
          Bucket: env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        },
      },
      actionOptions: {
        upload: {},
        uploadStream: {},
        delete: {},
      },
    },
  },
});

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({ "react-icons": true, });

config/middleware.js
module.exports = [
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::errors',
  {
    name: 'strapi::security',
    config: {
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        useDefaults: true,
        directives: {
          'connect-src': ["'self'", 'https:'],
          'img-src': [
            "'self'",
            'data:',
            'blob:',
            'dl.airtable.com',
            'ssp-server-strapi-seed.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
          ],
          'media-src': [
            "'self'",
            'data:',
            'blob:',
            'dl.airtable.com',
            'ssp-server-strapi-seed.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
          ],
          upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
        },
      },
    },

type here

  },
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::query',
  'strapi::body',
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];

package.json
{
  "name": "emvigostrapi",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@strapi/plugin-cloud": "4.23.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-graphql": "^4.24.0",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.23.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.23.1",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3": "^4.24.0",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.23.1",
    "mysql": "2.18.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.4",
    "strapi-plugin-react-icons": "^0.2.2",
    "styled-components": "5.3.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "f5e0be03-0813-48a6-8339-"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0 <=20.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}

Any suggestions on why this might have suddenly stopped working?

You should try nesting accessKeyId and secretAccessKey inside the credentials object:
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: 'aws-s3',
      providerOptions: {
        credentials: {
          accessKeyId: env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
          secretAccessKey: env("AWS_ACCESS_SECRET"),
        },
        region: env('AWS_REGION'),
        params: {
          ACL: env('AWS_ACL', 'public-read'),
          signedUrlExpires: env('AWS_SIGNED_URL_EXPIRES', 15 * 60),
          Bucket: env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        },
      },
      actionOptions: {
        upload: {},
        uploadStream: {},
        delete: {},
      },
    },
  },
});

